# Computer keeps restarting after upgrading my router

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, router, bsod

We recently updated our Internet connection to Fiber from regular cable. We also had to change our router for compatibility. All the devices in home can connect without any issue with the Wifi. However, my PC keeps shutting down with a BSOD and Stop Code `DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL`. It also says that `tcpip.sys` failed.

After that, the computer restarts but now it shuts down again with the error `SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION`. What failed still says `tcpip.sys`.

1. The PC does not restart like this when I am connecting to other Wifi connections such as my mobile hotspot.
2. The PC also connects properly without any issues if I use Ethernet cable to directly plug in the router.

I have tried the following:

1. Run the following command as Admin `netsh int ip reset`.
2. Check for driver updates. It keeps saying all drivers are up to date.

How can I get rid of this error?

I am using Windows 10 build 19041.

Thanks.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart It says 802.11n USB Wirless LAN Card. Manufacturer: Ralink Technology Corp

Comment: @Tim_Stewart It says QHMPL 0219 UL on the adapter. It is like a short USB stick and I just plug it into a USB port on the CPU. :)

Comment: The only other thing that would make sense to me is this, your old router was using 20Mhz wide channels and the new one is either using 20/40 dynamic, or strict 40Mhz wide channels. Try setting it to 20Mhz only and see what happens. Maybe it can't deal with wider channels for whatever reason

Comment: Thanks @Tim_Stewart I was very hopeful that this could be the issue as the router was set at 40MHz. Unfortunately, changing it to 20MHz did not have any effect and the PC shut down after a few minutes with the same `DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL` exception.

Comment: One thing that I have noticed is that my Internet speed slows down significantly (with this new router) whenever I connect to the WiFi. It is around 150Mbps with the Ethernet cable and around 20Mbps with the Wifi adapter before the PC shuts down. Does that help in figuring out the issue?

Comment: The error you are receiving seems to be driver related. It means the driver went to use a memory address that's invalid. This is why I had you try to update them. The only other thing I can guess is that it **is** a valid address, and one of your memory sticks is faulty. (Which would mean the new router and this error is just coincidence). Try running windows memory diagnostics and see what it reports.